# How do I get this to not repeat?

Tags: css, background

I'm new to CSS/HTML formats, and i'm using a base from [Eggy](https://toyhou.se/Eggy). They have in the CSS an option to put in a background, but however, it repeats on the x and y, no matter the size of the file. How do I get this to stop?

Here's the line of code:

```
$bg_image:"IMG_URL";
```

Comment: target the css selector and add background repeat property => `.selector { background-repeat: no-repeat; }`

Answer (score 0):

### According to [`https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-repeat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-repeat)

**The Usage of `no-repeat` in `background-repeat`**

#### A small example:

```css
.block
{
  position: relative;
  
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  
  border: 1px solid black;
  
  background-image: url("https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/examples/moon.jpg");
  background-size: 100px;
  
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.repeat
{
  background-repeat: repeat;
}
```

```html
<!--The block with no-repeating images-->
<div class="block"></div>

<!--The block with repeating images-->
<div class="block repeat"></div>
```